# Are Tunnel FETs (TFETs) already employed in some real world application?

Tags: semiconductors

I recently learned about the existence of such beasts as [TFETs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_field-effect_transistor).

I searched the Internet and it seems to me that this device is still under heavy lab research and I got the impression that industrial development has not started yet, let alone its use in a real world application, albeit experimental or high-end.

Am I right in thinking so? Has anyone any clue about whether TFETs are already being manufactured industrially, either as discrete parts (maybe unlikely) or as part of an IC design?

I'm interested in industrially or commercially available parts, but I'd also like to know about prototype devices used in  actually deployed equipment (maybe some gazillion-dollar gizmo for a super-exotic application).

Comment: Reading the Wiki article, I believe you'll never see a discrete one to play with, the advantages come in the billion transistor range. So we'll have to wait until they can make billions in the process used now for one, or they learn how to make one in a process scalable to billions. (Or make our own, for completeness sake)

Comment: In general IC manufacturers are not so keen on these kind of "different" devices unless they can easily adapt the current production techniques to make TFETs. The "intrinsic" silicon in the drawing on wikipedia might be just that. In normal IC processes there is no such thing as intrinsic silicon. All silicon has a doping of some sort because that can be controlled. Being able to make a device under lab conditions does not mean it warrants the investments needed to do mass production.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yep! That's the impression I got from my search: it's all theory and a little bit of research lab prototyping.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Sorry...

Comment: I'm going to guess that they will be used in industry, if and when it happens, first as a sensor/transducer offering one or some desirable, unique characteristic(s) in one or two specialized areas.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is 'not yet' for a commercial part. When they come out, they might get a different name, because TFET is already in use as the acronym for Trench FET.

Since I don't have any inside information, I would watch for the parts from manufacturers that already make exotic parts that have intrinsic silicon. For example, Avago Technologies makes PIN diodes. The I in PIN stands for intrinsic.

Intrinsic silicon is not rare. It is just an undoped wafer.